# Image Manipulation seam carving - order of carving

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, seam-carving

Lets say I'd like to remove 10 vertical seams and 10 horizontal seams from an image.
Does it matter if i remove 10 vertical seams first and then the 10 horizontal seams?
Should I do one vertical seams and then one horizontal seams and so on?

Is there a difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to always remove the seam that has the lowest energy -- whether vertical or horizontal. Of course, you may just end up removing the seam that corresponds to the smallest dimension in your image (a vertical seam for a landscape image, or horizontal seam for a portrait) since it will more likely have low energy.

Seam carving isn't really an exact science and has been improved in many ways in the meantime